# System.ServiceModel Error While trying to open ASP.net website

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I tried to open ASP.Net Website , but I received this error.

Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

what is this about ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below links are very much helpful you can refer to it :
     http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/04/28/system-typeloadexception-for-system-   servicemodel-activation-httpmodule-in-asp-net-4.aspx

```
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/39571e42-aca7-469d-8c68-aa59c2da4fcc
```

This error can occur when IIS is installed after installing .NET Framework 4, or if the 3.0 version of the WCF Http Activation module is installed after installing IIS and .NET Framework 4.

To resolve this problem, you must use the ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool (Aspnet_regiis.exe,) to register the correct version of ASP.NET. This can be accomplished by using the –iru parameters when running aspnet_regiis.exe as follows:

aspnet_regiis.exe -iru

OR

%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i

good luck